# Setting weights in Keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, convolution

I need help setting custom weights to a tiny custom Keras model for a 2D convolution. I have an input that looks like this:

```py
X = [[[3, 2, -4],
      [0, 5, 4],
      [2, -1, -7],
      [-7, 0, 1]],
     [[-8, 9, 1],
      [-3, 6, 0],
      [0, -4, 2],
      [5, 1, 1]]]
```

So, it can be think of a 4x3 image with only two channels. And my kernel looks like this:

```py
kernel = [[[2, 1],
           [0, -1],
           [0, -1]],
          [[1, 2],
           [2, -1],
           [2, -2]]]
```

So, a two dimensional 3x2 kernel. Doing by hand a 2D convolution with stride of 1 and no padding, yields:

```py
[[10, 14],
 [27, 16]]
```

Unfortunately, the following Keras code:

```py
model = Sequential()
conv2d = Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(3,2), strides=1, input_shape=(2,4,3), use_bias=False)
model.add(conv2d)
layer = model.layers[0]
layer.set_weights([np.array(kernel).reshape(3, 2, 2, 1)])
print(model.predict(np.array(X).reshape((1,) + np.shape(X))))
```

Outputs:

```py
[[19, -6],
 [-39, 16]]
```

I couldn't figure out how does Keras organize its kernels for the convolution. So far, looks very counterintuitive, but am probably missing something.

I am using Keras 2.0.9 with Tensorflow 1.4.0 as backend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kernels in keras follow this shape: `(height, width, input_channels, output_channels)` -- even when you're using `channels_first`.

You're right in thinking it uses a shape `(3,2,2,1)`

But your manual calculation is considering an inverted shape. In your manual calculation you're using `(input_channels, height, width)`.

When you `reshape` the kernel, you're not reordering these dimensions properly. Just reshaping is not equivalent to "transposing" the array. Reshape simply regroups the data without any kind of reordering.

To achieve a correct result in keras, you need to swap the axes properly:

```
#start as (input_channels, height, width) = (2,3,2)    
kernel = np.array([[[2, 1],
       [0, -1],
       [0, -1]],
      [[1, 2],
       [2, -1],
       [2, -2]]])

#change to (height, input_channels, width) = (3,2,2)   
kernel = kernel.swapaxes(0,1)

#change to (height, width, input_channels) = (3,2,2)
kernel = kernel.swapaxes(1,2)

#add output_channels
kernel = kernel.reshape((3,2,2,1))
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about how to do this in TensorFlow (which uses the same convention). How can you visualize this? I mean, I'm not able to see how a simple axis swap would achieve the desired result.

Comment: Suppose you have the matrix `[[1,2,3] , [4,5,6]]`. It has shape `(2,3)`. Now, this is a **reshape to (3,2)**: `[[1,2] , [3,4] , [5,6]]`. And this is an **axis swap**: `[[1,4] , [2,5] , [3,6]]`.